# Complex Gradient Pattern

Tags: gradient, patterns, effects

I'm in love with this pattern. Multiple gradients with a sort of CRT monitor-come-print control strip pattern, that also works in gradient.

https://www.hingston.net/work/soph-x-hingston-studio/

Can anyone suggest ways this sort of effect can be recreated – I'm less interested in the text and crosshair layers but would love to know how to create that cellular pattern! Happy for suggestions in most adobe programs

Comment: What *software* is used would matter. I *don't* think it's overly complex. It's just a series of rectangles with different gradient fills. The gradient files are carefully aligned to work with neighboring rectangles.

Comment: It seems the strength of the blend is also a gradient though. Some areas have greater opacity and some have less so. Iim assuming this is After Effects, but unsure how I'd go about recreating that level of complexity. I can approximate it in illustrator, but it looks 10% as good.

Comment: Seems like a pattern of gradients blended over some colorful noise. I would experiment with different repeated gradients and different blending modes. I don't know an easy way to do that in Adobe software, but it's [very easy in Blender](https://i.imgur.com/gUcrAEW.png) You could ask on Blender Stack Exchange for more detailed answer. Obviously one would need a lot more experimentation than I did. Also the effect is sort of hard to see in the images on the website.